# Creation of a system made of class inside a function and used in the main part

Tags: python, class

I do not know which way is the best to achieve my goal, so any proposition is welcome.

I have a python script which is composed of the following:

```
Class1
Class2
Class3
Class4
...
+ some functions
```

Each class actually mimic the component of a system (digital analog converter, microcontroller, serial peripheral interface, ...). To create the system, I am doing this in the main part:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    elt1 = Class1(param1)
    elt2 = Class1(param2)
    elt3 = Class1(param3)
    elt1 = Class2(param4)
    ...
```

I have a lot of element to create in order to create the system. Each has to be remade for each new simulation, thus if I want to preprogram multiple simulation, it takes quite some space (basically, I have to copy paste 100 line of code each time).

I would like to define a function: `creation of the system`. Currently it looks like this:

```
def creation_system(parameters):
    elt1 = Class1(param1)
    elt2 = Class1(param2)
    elt3 = Class1(param3)
    elt1 = Class2(param4)
    ...
```

The system is now define in the local memory space of the function, and I would like to access it in the main part in order to do:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for simulation_parameter in parameters:
        creation_system(parameters)
        compute()
        save_result()
```

The 2 ways to do this that I can thought of is either to return each of the elements created at the end of the function (in a tuple I guess), or to define them as global. I have about 40 variables (elts) created, thus none is really handy. Any other possibility?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you need to create a new `System` class containing all the elements. Than you can pass the parameters to the constructor of this class.

This is a code example:

```
class System(object):

    def __init__(self, parameters):
        self.element0 = Class0 (parameters[0])
        self.element1 = Class1 (parameters[1])
        self.element2 = Class2 (parameters[2])

    def compute(): 
        ....

    def save_result():
        ....

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parameters = ...
    mySystem = System(parameters)
    mySystem.compute()
    mySystem.save_result()
```

Alternatively, you could have a general class with only the elements common to all the systems (similar to the one above), and then create new classes that inherit from the previous one and have specialized behavior:

```
class SpecificSystem(System):

    def __init__(self, parameters):
        super().__init__(parameters)
        # Additional elements specific to this system
        self.element3 = Class3 (parameters[3])

    def compute():
        # Behavior specific to this system
        ....

    # Retain save_result() from superclass
```

Comment: Indeed that is a third possibility which might be more handy.

Comment: For simplicity, that's the solution I've took. Some slight change, I put the computation function aside, in order to use multiprocessing. Not too ugly, and it works :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you have two scripts called `components.py` which your component classes and functions are defined in and `main.py` which is the main code to be run.

If you define the `__all__` attribute in the `components.py` which inludes names of all your component classes like:

```
__all__ = ['Class1', 'Class2', 'Class3', ...(and so on)]
```

Then in `main.py`, you can instantiate all these classes **with a single for loop**:

```
import components

if __name__ == "__main__":
    comp_dict = {}
    for cls_name in components.__all__:
        comp_dict[cls_name] = getattr(components, cls_name)()
```

All we has done here was getting all classes using **getattr** built-in function and instantiating in a for loop.

You can also pass initial params in for loop if you want.

Comment: Thanks for the proposition, so indeed I should split my script into 2 files. When I'll do it, I'll try this method which looks very clean and compact. Where does the `__all__` attribute be define? top of the file? in a system class?